# How can duplicate the data records based on period?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set as periodic. However, these periods are not consecutive. My data pattern is like that

```
Period  Customer_No Date        Product
1       111         01.01.2017  X
3       111         05.09.2017  Y
8       111         02.05.2018  Z
6       222         02.02.2017  X
9       222         06.04.2017  Z
12      222         05.09.2018  B
15      222         02.01.2019  A
```

End of the period should be 15 for all customers. I want to create consecutive periods based on customers and fill them with previous data like below:

```
Period  Customer_No Date        Product
1       111         01.01.2017  X
2       111         01.01.2017  X
3       111         05.09.2017  Y
4       111         05.09.2017  Y
5       111         05.09.2017  Y
6       111         05.09.2017  Y
7       111         05.09.2017  Y
8       111         02.05.2018  Z
9       111         02.05.2018  Z
10      111         02.05.2018  Z
11      111         02.05.2018  Z
12      111         02.05.2018  Z
13      111         02.05.2018  Z
14      111         02.05.2018  Z
15      111         02.05.2018  Z
6       222         02.02.2017  X
7       222         02.02.2017  X
8       222         02.02.2017  X
9       222         06.04.2017  Z
10      222         06.04.2017  Z
11      222         06.04.2017  Z
12      222         05.09.2018  B
13      222         05.09.2018  B
14      222         05.09.2018  B
15      222         02.01.2019  A


create table tbl_cust(period int,Customer_No int, Date date, Product varchar)

insert into tbl_cust values(1,111,'01.01.2017','X')
insert into tbl_cust values(3,111,'05.09.2017','Y')
insert into tbl_cust values(8,111,'02.05.2018','Z')
insert into tbl_cust values(6,222,'02.02.2017','X')
insert into tbl_cust values(9,222,'06.04.2017','Z')
insert into tbl_cust values(12,222,'05.09.2018','B')
insert into tbl_cust values(15,222,'02.01.2019','A')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the rows that you want.  Then you need to fill them in with the most recent data.  What you really want is `lag(ignore nulls)`, but SQL Server does not support that functionality.

There are only up to 15 rows per customer, so `apply` is a reasonable alternative:

```
with cte as (
      select min(period) as period, customer_no
      from tbl_cust
      group by customer_no
      union all
      select period + 1, customer_no
      from cte
      where period < 15
     )
select cte.period, cte.customer_no, c.date, c.product
from cte cross apply
     (select top (1) c.*
      from tbl_cust c
      where c.customer_no = cte.customer_no and
            c.period <= cte.period
      order by c.period desc
     ) c
order by cte.customer_no, cte.period;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a60836d254d376f461d6e727303351ef) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: shouldn't the cross apply part be " where cte.customer_no = c.customer_no and
         cte.period >= c.period
      order by c.period desc ", since we have to fill with previous data and not next ?

Comment: @ShikharArora . . . Good catch.  The aliases were backwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
select ID as period, Customer_No, [Date], Product from 
    (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15)) P(ID)
        OUTER APPLY( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer_No ORDER BY period desc) RN 
            FROM tbl_cust C WHERE C.period <= P.ID ) X
WHERE X.RN = 1
ORDER BY Customer_No, ID
```

Result:

```
period      Customer_No Date       Product
----------- ----------- ---------- -------
1           111         2017-01-01 X
2           111         2017-01-01 X
3           111         2017-05-09 Y
4           111         2017-05-09 Y
5           111         2017-05-09 Y
6           111         2017-05-09 Y
7           111         2017-05-09 Y
8           111         2018-02-05 Z
9           111         2018-02-05 Z
10          111         2018-02-05 Z
11          111         2018-02-05 Z
12          111         2018-02-05 Z
13          111         2018-02-05 Z
14          111         2018-02-05 Z
15          111         2018-02-05 Z
6           222         2017-02-02 X
7           222         2017-02-02 X
8           222         2017-02-02 X
9           222         2017-06-04 Z
10          222         2017-06-04 Z
11          222         2017-06-04 Z
12          222         2018-05-09 B
13          222         2018-05-09 B
14          222         2018-05-09 B
15          222         2019-02-01 A
```

Comment: Serkan, thank you very much, your solution's works.